# Hash dereference in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, dereference

I have a HASH reference `$job` which has this data:

```
{
    "opstat"  : "ok",
    "response": {
                "group_id":23015,
                "order_id":"139370",
                "job_count":"10",
                "credits_used":"100.45",
                "currency":"USD"
                }
}
```

I want to print the hash value of "response" key.
I tried doing this but did not work

`print %{$job->{'response'}}`

Edit

I do not want any formatting. I want to know how to access each element in the value of 'response' key.

Comment: Actually I think you *do not* have a "hash reference, but a JSON structure. Please show the code and any messages you get!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know how to access each element in the value of 'response' key.

By definition, you need some kind of loop. A foreach loop is typical, although you could also use `map`.

```
for my $key (keys %{$job->{response}}) {
   my  $val = $job->{response}{$key};
   print("$key: $val\n");  # Or whatever
}
```

or

```
my $response = $job->{response};
for my $key (keys %$response) {
   my  $val = $response->{$key};
   print("$key: $val\n");  # Or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code, this is a real & complete script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $job = {
    'opstat' => 'ok',
    'response' => {
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'group_id' => ':23015',
        'job_count' => '10',
        'order_id' => '139370',
        'credits_used' => '100.45'
    }
};

foreach my $key (keys %{$job}) {
    print "key=$key|value=$job->{$key}\n";

    # Testing if "$job->{$key}" is a HASH ref
    # ...if yes, we iterate inside the HASH
    #  through the next level.
    if (ref($job->{$key}) eq "HASH") {
        foreach my $key2 (keys %{$job->{$key}}) {
            print "\tkey=$key2|value=$job->{$key}->{$key2}\n"; 
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output :

```
key=opstat|value=ok
key=response|value=HASH(0x1638998)
        key=currency|value=USD
        key=group_id|value=:23015
        key=order_id|value=139370
        key=job_count|value=10
        key=credits_used|value=100.45
```

If you want to access "group_id" key :

```
print $job->{response}->{group_id};
```

If you only want to access "response" HASH without testing anything :

```
foreach my $key (keys %{$job->{response}}) {
    print "key=$key|value=$job->{response}->{$key}\n";
}
```

or with with this `while` loop and `each` :

```
while (my ($key,$value) = each %{$job->{response}}){
    print "key=$key|value=$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper( $job->{response} );
```

or individually ...

```
print $job->{response}{group_id};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve; your code would print the contents of the inner hash without any formatting. If you want a formatted output, you'd have to use the [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) module:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $job = {
  "opstat" => "ok",
  "response" => {
    "group_id":23015,
    "order_id":"139370",
    "job_count":"10",
    "credits_used":"100.45",
    "currency":"USD"
  }
};
print Dumper($job->{'response'});
```